# Why are subtitles not showing in SMPlayer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, subtitles, media-player, mplayer

My OS is ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I am using SMPlayer 19.10.2.

Randomly some videos do not display subtitles, gives no error when loading subtitle file… Recently, one of the videos that should display subtitles is no longer working. I reinstalled that but it was useless.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

General > Multimedia engine choose other and set `/usr/bin/mplayer`
if you wanna use 2 subtitles you have to install  `sudo apt install mpv` and set multimedia engine `/usr/bin/mpv`

Answer (score -2):

SMPLAYER doesn't show ANY subtitles in Windows 10 for an archived video  (Handbrake)  -- WTF -- Laewo and VLC show the subtitles without a problem ...

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: FYI, just compared smplayer and vlc, and smplayer runs more flawlessly, and no pb with subtitles...